# Why am I unable to assign an embedded ArrayList<Integer> to a locally declared ArrayList<Integer>?

Tags: java, arraylist, linkedhashmap

Sorry if the title is not clear, I'm not very good with programming jargon.

I have 2 string ArrayLists and an integer ArrayList obtained from one method which is passed to a separate method through the collection **LinkedHashMap< String, List< String>>**. However, when I try to set the integer ArrayList into a empty ArrayList declared in the receiving method, it shows the syntax error: "incompatible types: **List< String>** cannot be converted to **List< Integer>**".

Starter Method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try{

    LinkedHashMap lhm = new LinkedHashMap();
    List<String> listEPC = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> listTimeStamp = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Integer> listAntenna = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    String tagID = "EQ5237";
    String TimeStampStr = "12:23:22";
    int tagAntenna = 2;        

            listEPC.add(tagID);
            listTimeStamp.add(TimeStampStr);
            listAntenna.add(tagAntenna);

            lhm.put("epcs", listEPC);
            lhm.put("timestamps", listTimeStamp);
            lhm.put("antennas", listAntenna);

   insertData insert = new insertData();
   insert.insertData(lhm);                    //send map with values to new method

    }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Receiving Method:

```
public class insertData {

    public void insertData(LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>> readMap) {

            List<String> listEPC = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> listTimeStamp = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<Integer> listAntenna = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            String EPC = null;
            String TimeStamp = null;
            Integer Antenna = null;

            listEPC = readMap.get("epcs");
            listTimeStamp = readMap.get("timestamps");
            listAntenna = readMap.get("antennas");      //error message here

            for(int i=0; i<readMap.size(); i++){

                EPC = listEPC.get(i);
                TimeStamp = listTimeStamp.get(i);
                Antenna = listAntenna.get(i);

                System.out.println("Entry " + i );
                System.out.println("Values: " + EPC + TimeStamp + Antenna);
            }
          }
}
```

This code works only if I change all instances of integers to strings, which is not what I would like in my actual code. Why is it so and how do I work around it?

Comment: Because your LinkedHashmap contains List<String> not List<Integer>. You're going to have to cast.

Comment: Do you want to iterate over `readMap.size()`? That will not be the same length as your lists contained within the map.

Comment: @matt "You're going to have to cast" Doesn't sound type-safe to me.

Comment: @AndyTurner depends on how you cast, in my answer I illustrated two ways to cast. One of them is "type-safe", in that it will throw an exception. I also included a suggestion to improve the form.

Comment: Don't use raw types in code: `LinkedHashMap lhm = new LinkedHashMap();` should have generics on it. If you add generics, you'll find a type error in the `main` method too.

Comment: @matt I commented because the implication of your comment is that you have to cast from `List<String>` to `List<Integer>`. Your answer below adds more information by pointing out the use of the wildcard.

Comment: A general advice: your IDE warns you about using raw-types for the exact reason you've got an issue here. Either consistently use raw types and limit the operations on content down to a level that is guaranteed to be provided by all objects in the datastructure - pretty useless practically -, or consistently use generics. Otherwise your code will get pretty error-prone.

Comment: So instead of `LinkedHashMap lhm = new LinkedHashMap` I should try to use `LinkedHashMap<String, Map> lhm = new LinkedHashMap<String, Map>();` instead then, got it.

Comment: @Lagostax no, that is still using a raw type in the `Map` - and why `Map` anyway? `LinkedHashMap<String, List<?>>` would work in your `main` method.

Comment: I did mean list, my bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't assign a `List<String>` to a `List<Integer>`. The elements are fundamentally different types.

You would need to construct a new `List`:

```
List<Integer> listOfIntegers = new ArrayList<>();
for (String entry : listOfStrings) {
  listOfIntegers.add(Integer.valueOf(entry);
}
```

Of course, you also need to handle the possibility that elements of the list cannot be parsed as integers.

---

However, you are just throwing away type information by stuffing everything into a single map. It would be better to pass the three lists separately:

```
insertData(listEPC, listTimestamp, listAntenna);
```

and then you can have different list types in the method signature:

```
void insertData(
    List<String> listEPC,
    List<String> listTimestamp,
    List<Integer> listAntenna) { ... }
```

Comment: If you look at how the OP created their map, your top solution will throw an exception because one of their lists actually is a `List<Integer>`

Comment: @matt yep. I have commented on the use of raw types above.

Comment: Thanks! I was under the impression that the only way to pass multiple groups of values was through a collection. This method is a much simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to include the proper answer at the bottom, but in regards to your question title, you'll have to change your method signature to:

```
LinkedHashmap<String, List<?>> readMap;
```

Then either cast the lists, which will cause an unsafe cast. eg.

```
List<String> listEPC = (List<String>)readMap.get("epcs");
```

Or cast the object.

```
List<?> listEPC = readMap.get("epcs");
```

Then in the loop cast.

```
 EPC = (String)listEPC.get(i);
```

Note, **these are not good solutions.**

What you should have is one List that contains an object with all of the data's you need.

I can imagine the thought process went something along these lines, "I have these things, and they contain two strings and an integer. I will create a variable for each." Then you ask the question, "How do I create a collection of these things?"

The wrong answer to this question is, "I will make a list for each value, and match associated values by index." The correct answer is, "I will create a class to represent my data, and store that in a list." This is the basic essence of object orient programming (welcome to java).

First we design the class:

```
class EPCThing{
    String EPC;
    String timeStamp;
    int Antennas;

    public EPCThing(String tagId, String timeStamp, int antennas){
        EPC=tagId;
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
        Antennas = antennas;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Values: " + EPC + TimeStamp + Antenna
    }

}
```

Now your program's main method will be something like.

```
List<EPCThing> things = new ArrayList<>();

String tagID = "EQ5237";
String TimeStampStr = "12:23:22";
int tagAntenna = 2;        

EPCThing thing = new EPCThing(tagID, TimeStampStr, tagAntenna);
things.add(thing);

insertData insert = new insertData();
insert.insertData(things);
```

Then we can fix your insertData method

```
public void insertData(List<EPCThing> things) {

    for(int i=0; i<things.size(); i++){

            System.out.println("Entry " + i );
            System.out.println("Values: " + things.get(i));

    }
}
```

Comment: The fundamental problem here is, that the map only contains strings mapped to lists of strings, but OP wants to retrieve a list of `Integer`. Casting won't do any good here, except for moving the error from compile- to runtime.

Comment: @Paul where the OP creates the map he inserts a List<Integer>.

Comment: I do want to reuse my data for other purposes aside from displaying it in a string, but there was a gross misunderstanding of passing values between methods on my part. Thanks for the explanation regardless, I've learnt a bit about the concept of casting.

Comment: @Lagostax I hope you can see how having a class that keeps all of the associated data together is useful for more than just displaying a string. You example doesn't need casting and it makes for a better program if you don't have casting.